# Function defined in abstract class won't return value of variable

Tags: php, inheritance, abstract-class, instance

How can I get the value of variable defined in abstract class that is changed in instance of a class that extends it, through a function that was defined in abstract class? The following code should help to illustrate my problem:

Abstract class:

```
abstract class Kontroler {
    private $pogled;
    function __construct(){
    }
    public function pogled(){
        return $this->pogled;
    }
    abstract function defolt();
}
```

Class that extends `Kontroler`:

```
class E404 extends Kontroler{
    function __construct (){
    }
    function defolt(){
        $this->pogled = 'aplikacija/viewsi/404/404.v.htm';
    }
}
```

My problem is that I change the value of `$pogled` inside an instance of the `E404` class, but when I call `$instanceOfE404->pogled();` PHP returns value of null which is value of `$pogled` defined in abstract class. Why is this?

Comment: If you declare $pogled as protected, rather than private, does that work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*private* in parent will remain private in the parent - child classes don't see it. Create a getter function or make it protected.

See [Visibility<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: Protected it is than. Thanks!